# How do I stop an HTML helper from encoding the value attribute of an HTML element?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, underscore.js

I have this input element which works fine with underscore templating.

```
<input id="color" name="color" value="<%= color %>" />
```

I want to use the `Html.Helper` method to generate the element instead.

I initially tried just the basic helper

```
@Html.TextBox("color", "<%= color %>")
```

But that gives me

```
<input id="color" name="color" type="text" value="&lt;%= color %>" />
```

I tried wrapping the value attribute with `Html.Raw` but that gives the same result, and wrapping the entire helper results in the same thing.

The entire block is wrapped in a `<script type="text/template">` tag.

Why is it converting `<` to `&lt;` and how do I get it to stop?

This works, but is a little messy

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.TextBox("color", "<%= color %>").ToString().Replace("&lt;", "<"))
```

Comment: Because attribute values are supposed to be encoded.

Comment: I think your problem is that you're using an HTML generation tool to generate `text/plain` that just happens to look an awful lot like `text/html` but it isn't HTML and shouldn't be treated as HTML.

Comment: @muistooshort, I have the code wrapped a in `text/template` tag, but the Razor helpers don't exactly care about that when they generate the code. Underscore doesn't handle the `&lt;` like I hoped it would. I'm just looking for a way to make Razor and Underscore.js work together.

Comment: I don't know Razor so I can't help you with that. Have you considered simply writing the template by hand? Your `Replace` kludge can fail if Razor decides to HTML-encode other things or if it encodes things that should be encoded. It boils down to this: you probably shouldn't be using an HTML generation tool to generate something that isn't HTML.

Comment: @muistooshort, fair enough. The only reason I was trying was because Razor also generates client validation code based on server side annotations. Makes life a little easier.

Comment: That's the problem with all-in-one solutions: you can't get out of the box without throwing away the whole box. I wish I knew of a magical DWIM flag for Razor so that I could offer better help than "don't do that". Can you override the attribute handling parts of `Html` to leave Underscore things alone? Or perhaps use [different delimiters](http://underscorejs.org/#template) for `_.template`?

Comment: @muistooshort, I switched to `{{ }}` delimiters, which fixes the issue for input elements, but in things like Form Actions or Action Links (anything that generates URLs as part of the markup), I run into the same problems again.

Comment: Maybe you need to use delimiters that are HTML-safe and URI-safe.

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to use a color that is supplied from the code-behind would it not be better to put a Color property on a model that is bound to the view?  Then you could use:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string ColorField {get;set;} //not sure whether you wanted string color or hex color here.  CHange it as necessary
    //also add whatever else you need the UI to bind to
}
```

In your controller, when you set up the model, you would put in the default value:

```
public ViewResult MyViewName()
{
     MyModel model = new MyModel { ColorField = "blue"; // or hex color / etc.}
     //add other initialization here
     return View(model);
}
```

then on your view

```
@model MyModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.ColorField, "color")
```

It looks to me like you're mixing traditional ASP.NET syntax with Razor syntax, but I haven't used ASP.NET syntax with MVC so I could be wrong, I wanted a clean break from the old.

Regardless, the way I have described above is how I always place default values into my form fields and it works great.

Comment: The `<%= color %>` is for the client-side Underscore template: http://underscorejs.org/#template

Comment: @anyeone, mu is correct. I'm using Backbone/Underscore.js on the client side. The `<% %` is ASP.NET syntax, but in this case it's being used with Underscore.js templating.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.  My bad!